# How can we differentiate PC SAS with SAS Server

Tags: sas

We need to identify what type of SAS(pc SAS or Server SAS) we are using now. Is there any way to find out what SAS we are using, means PC SAS or SAS Server?

Answer (score 5):

using "proc setinit; run;" you will see for what type of Machine your SAS installation is registered,
if it contains "Workstation" than you have your answer :)

To be more precise, let me know what shows under OSNAME and I will confirm it to you!

A rule good to know, only Windows machine can be "workstations" if you're under Linux, Aix, HP-UX or Solaris you probably have a server license depending on the number of core you declared

Regards,
Younes

Comment: Hi, thanks for Ur response. below is the details of my System.   Operating System:   W32_WKS .
Products:                                                           Base/SAS SAS/STAT                                                            SAS/GRAPH                                                           SAS/QC                                                             
SAS Integration SAS/ACCESS Interface to ORACLE                                  
SAS Workspace Server for Local Access

Comment: W32_WKS means workstation. You are using Base SAS plus some extra modules.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the automatic macro variables `SYSSCP` and `SYSSCPL`.

Examples :

```
/* Windows */
%PUT &SYSSCP ;
%PUT &SYSSCPL ;

SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSSCP resolves to WIN
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSSCPL resolves to XP_PRO

/* Unix */
%PUT &SYSSCP ;
%PUT &SYSSCPL ;

SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSSCP resolves to AIX 64
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSSCPL resolves to AIX
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using the _SASSERVERNAME variable. When connecting via a interface such as EG or PC SAS running

```
%put &_SASSERVERNAME;
```

should provide an answer such as 'Local' or your SAS server name. Furthermore you can use that variable in macro code to run conditional logic based on which server you're connected to.

```
%macro server;
%if &_SASSERVERNAME = 'Local' %then %do;

%end %else %if &_SASSERVERNAME = 'MYSERVER' %then %do;

%end;
%mend server;

%server
```

Best,